# How to type a function that only accepts a Readonly Ref in Vue 3?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

In Vue 3, you can create a readonly ref or reactive by simply wrapping it with `readonly(myRef)`.

Is there a way to enforce a function is called only with a Readonly Ref at compile time?

e.g. this should be a compile error:

```
const name = ref('Susan');

function blah(someRef: Readonly<any>) {
  // ...
}

blah(name);
```

Answer (score 7):

The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66318440/how-to-type-a-function-that-only-accepts-a-readonly-ref-in-vue-3#comment117433016_66418246) by nogridbag is correct. Use the `DeepReadonly` type:

```
import { readonly, ref } from 'vue'; // or from '@vue/composition-api'
import type { DeepReadonly } from 'vue'; // or from '@vue/composition-api'

const name = ref('Susan');
const readonlyName = readonly(name); // type: DeepReadonly<Ref<string>>

function blah(someRef: DeepReadonly<any>) {
  // ...
}

blah(name);
blah(readonlyName);
```

Answer (score -2):

You would use the `Ref` type:

```
import type { Ref } from "vue";

function blah(someRef: Ref<string>) {
  // ...
}
```

You may find however, that it is better to pass values around, rather than refs.

Comment: That would not enforce the readonly property of a Ref. I looked into the typings in Vue and so far using DeepReadonly<Ref<T>> is working nicely.